# Python parallelisation queuing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I parallelise asynchronously with the following snippet

```
p = Pool(cpu_count(), initializer=initializer, initargs=(counter, lock))
                                                             
for x_i in range(0, len(x)):
    arglist.append((x[x_i], x_i, retdict,))

result = p.starmap(func=obj, iterable=arglist)
p.close()
p.join()
p.terminate()
```

The above snippet assigns each process tasks from my arglist i.e. process 0 gets a chunk, process 1 gets a chunk.

The problem is some of the processes finish all their tasks and just wait. I'd really like these processes to take on pending tasks. I cannot a-priori predict how long a task takes thus, it is not possible for me to decide chunks.

Is there an intrinsic python method which achieves what I aim to do? What I expect is that a process takes on the next task from the arglist like below:

```
**START**

process_0 -> arglist[0]
process_1 -> arglist[1]
.
.
.
process_n -> arglist[n]

** process_0 finishes earlier than others **
process_0 -> arglist[n+1]

** core_i finishes next **
process_i -> arglist[n+2]
```

Comment: Tasks (chunks of a job) are assigned to worker-processes, not cores. What you're probably really looking for is starmap's [`chunksize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)-parameter.

Comment: @Darkonaut If I set chunksize to 1 does that work?

Comment: You need to set `chunksize=1`. It will work because tasks get distributed one by one. As soon a worker finishes a task, it will try to fetch another task from an internal queue. It's not a directed distribution, workers just wait on a queue and whichever comes first gets first (kind of).

Comment: What @Darkonaut has said is the only way I know of ensuring that jobs are not sitting on the queue waiting for a process to complete while other processes are sitting idle with no work to do. That said, in general, using a larger chunksize enqueues work more efficiently (but you have bigger problems).

Answer (score -1):

In the first place, that is meaningless. Parallel and sequential are diametrically opposed. Each calculation is affected by various factors, so time of calculations are all different. You can somehow try to let tasks run sequentially with shared object or manually operating `Process`, but finishes must scatter.